# Difficulty Loading New Page w/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'm writing a basic Flask app.  I have a page called `/searchByCollege` that consists of a bunch of buttons, each with a team name as their text, and .college as their class.

I've written some JS so that, when the user clicks on a button, it'll load `/searchByCollege/collegeName`, where `collegeName` is the text of the button they just clicked on.  Here's what I have:

```
<script>
$('.college').on('click', function() {
    var baseURL = $('#baseURL').text();
    var finalURL = baseURL + "/" + this.text();
    window.location.href = finalURL;
    return false;
})
</script>
```

I didn't originally include `return false;` and nothing happened upon clicking a button.  Then I added `return false;` and I got the same result.  I've inspected the HTML and the base URL is correct (it's just `/searchByCollege`).  I've looked at the requests as I click on the button and none are being made.

I've loaded jQuery above this through Google's CDN so that's not the issue.

Any other ideas?

Thanks for the help,
bclayman

Comment: Are you sure the function is even being called? If you put `alert("click")` in it, do you see the alert? I suspect you just need to put the code into `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Is #baseURL a hidden field?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the document to load by using `$(document).ready`:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.college').on('click', function() {
        var baseURL = $('#baseURL').text();
        var finalURL = baseURL + "/" + this.text();
        window.location.href = finalURL;
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.text()
```

needs to be changed to

```
$(this).text()
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out where you were getting the 'baseURL'  Since you are using just JQuery you need to call .value and not .text()

```
<button class="college" value="CSU">CSU</button>

$('.college').on('click', function(){
    var baseURL = "/searchByCollege";
    var finalURL = baseURL + "/" + this.value;
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

you can try this

```
window.location.hostname = finalURL;
window.location.pathname = '';
```

Comment: `finalURL` contains a full URL, not just a hostname.

Comment: what about

`window.location = finalURL;`

Comment: That's equivalent to `window.location.href = finalURL`, which is in the original code.